# how to display current progress on progress bar when activity comes to foreground

Tags: android, android-activity, progress-bar

I am using progress bar for displaying status of data download from server using AsynkTask.

I have written  a callback method from which I update the progress

```
@Override
public void onBookDownloadProgressUpdated(int value) 
{
    if(_bookProgressBar == null)
    {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) latestLinearLayout.findViewWithTag(layoutTagQueue.peek());
        _bookProgressBar = (ProgressBar) linearLayout.getChildAt(1);
    }
    _bookProgressBar.setProgress(value);
}
```

This works fine.But when user goes to another screen and coming back to that screen then the progress bar didn't show any progress while the downloading is going on in the background.
how to show current progress even user press the back key and revisit that screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below link for progress bar and put the method which will set the value of progress bar in onResume() instead of onCreate() or onStart().

Use a static variable(int) for showing the progress of progressbar.

[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

Comment: thank u...this problem is solved using static variable which maintains current progress